# awk paste comparison printing

Tags: awk, compare, paste

I have two files, each file has an md5 checksum of a file name. Both are in separate folders. When I paste these files, I am looking for a mechanism to do the following:

if $column 3 matches $column 6, solely print out those two side by side:

```
filename1 = md5_checksum filename2 = md5_checksum
filename3 = md5_checksum filename4 = md5_checksum
filename5 = md5_checksum filename6 = md5_checksum
```

Hopeful result:

```
filename1 = md5_checksum filename6 = md5_checksum
```

So imagine (or test) the output of:

```
md5 directoryA/* > checkA ; md5 directoryB/* > checkB
paste checkA checkB
```

I'd like to say: "Look in checkA, filename1 is also in checkB albeit a different name" (same checksum)

FYI, what I have tried:

```
awk > SIMILAR 'NR==FNR{ _[$4]=$4 next}{print $0, _[$4,$4] }' checkA checkB
```

($4 being the field on both files checkA and checkB)

---

Here is what I perceive is the best explanation as to what I'm trying to do. Sincerest thanks for answering so quickly:

```
# touch A/{fee,fie,foo,fum}
# touch B/{Bee,Bie,Boo,Bum}
# md5 B/* > checkB
# md5 A/* > checkA
# more checkA
MD5 (A/fee) = 2737b49252e2a4c0fe4c342e92b13285
MD5 (A/fie) = df8b712c4fe20a0df933819665770165
MD5 (A/foo) = 51ca4befb7cb5bd22766a33c73ffca5b
MD5 (A/fum) = a80b2c31cfc269e4aa2f48658b5349d9

# more checkB
# md5 B/*
MD5 (B/Bee) = b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1
MD5 (B/Bie) = 2737b49252e2a4c0fe4c342e92b13285
MD5 (B/Boo) = df8b712c4fe20a0df933819665770165
MD5 (B/Bum) = 51ca4befb7cb5bd22766a33c73ffca5b
```

If we see here, file foo in A (A/foo) is similar to B/Bum

I'd like the output to be something like:

```
A/foo B/Bum = 51ca4befb7cb5bd22766a33c73ffca5b
A/fee B/Bie = 2737b49252e2a4c0fe4c342e92b13285
```

Comment: your example output implies that your want to scan all lines against all other lines (by postion 3 v 6), is this your intent? Read up about `(f)grep -F -f listFile inFile > outFile` Good luck.

Comment: shellter thanks, but not really... Some files are named differently, e.g., checkA may have a file named foo with an md5 checksum of say 5, and on checkB the file might be name fee (yet the same md5 checksum)

Comment: Consider putting actual numbers in your test data instead of `md5_checksum`. Hard to tell your intent. Thanks for the addtional info and your code sample. Good luck.

Comment: Probably would help to have a tiny example with two input files and what they would look like in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the following:

> I'd like to say: "Look in checkA, filename1 is also in checkB albeit a
>   different name" (same checksum)

If you have two files with filename and checksum values then you can try something like this:

```
awk -F'=' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} $2 in a{print a[$2],$1,FS,$2}' checkA checkB
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat checkA
MD5 (A/fee) = 2737b49252e2a4c0fe4c342e92b13285
MD5 (A/fie) = df8b712c4fe20a0df933819665770165
MD5 (A/foo) = 51ca4befb7cb5bd22766a33c73ffca5b
MD5 (A/fum) = a80b2c31cfc269e4aa2f48658b5349d9

$ cat checkB
MD5 (B/Bee) = b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1
MD5 (B/Bie) = 2737b49252e2a4c0fe4c342e92b13285
MD5 (B/Boo) = df8b712c4fe20a0df933819665770165
MD5 (B/Bum) = 51ca4befb7cb5bd22766a33c73ffca5b

$ awk -F'=' 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1; next} $2 in a { print a[$2], $1, FS, $2}' checkA checkB
MD5 (A/fee)  MD5 (B/Bie)  =  2737b49252e2a4c0fe4c342e92b13285
MD5 (A/fie)  MD5 (B/Boo)  =  df8b712c4fe20a0df933819665770165
MD5 (A/foo)  MD5 (B/Bum)  =  51ca4befb7cb5bd22766a33c73ffca5b
```

#### Update:

You can use `gawk` to get your desired output by using `gensub` function.

```
$ gawk -F'=' 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1; next} $2 in a {print a[$2]=gensub(/.*\(([^)]+)\)/,"\\1","G",a[$2]), $1=gensub(/.*\(([^)]+)\)/,"\\1","G",$1), FS, $2}' checkA checkB
A/fee  B/Bie  =  2737b49252e2a4c0fe4c342e92b13285
A/fie  B/Boo  =  df8b712c4fe20a0df933819665770165
A/foo  B/Bum  =  51ca4befb7cb5bd22766a33c73ffca5b
```

Comment: This worked excellent Jaypal thanks. I made a quick modification to my output to make it work via your solution.

Comment: @munkeyoto Great! I updated the solution to match your input files.

Answer (score 2):

```
join -o 1.2,2.2,1.3,1.4 -j 4 <(sort -k4,4 checkA) <(sort -k4,4 checkB)
```

```
(A/fee) (B/Bie) = 2737b49252e2a4c0fe4c342e92b13285
(A/foo) (B/Bum) = 51ca4befb7cb5bd22766a33c73ffca5b
(A/fie) (B/Boo) = df8b712c4fe20a0df933819665770165
```

Pipe into `tr -d '()'` if you need to get rid of the parentheses.